# Threading Email for security system in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a security program written in python. It detects when someone is in front of the camera(machine learning) and sends to the owner one email message with the photo of the intruder.
My question is how can I thread the email function because I want to send the photo when the program finds the intruder. Now if it finds the intruder the execution stops till the photo is sent via email.  I tried with threading module but it does not work(I don't have experience in python threading). I can start just a single thread and I don't know how to make it send multiple photos with the same thread.(Without creating more threads).

```
def send_mail(path):
    sender = 'MAIL'
    gmail_password = 'PASS'
    recipients = ['OWNER']

# Create the enclosing (outer) message
    outer = MIMEMultipart()
    outer['Subject'] = 'Threat'
    outer['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(recipients)
    outer['From'] = sender
    outer.preamble = 'Problem.\n'

# List of attachments
    attachments = [path]

# Add the attachments to the message
    for file in attachments:
        try:
            with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
                msg = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
                msg.set_payload(fp.read())
            encoders.encode_base64(msg)
            msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', 
filename=os.path.basename(file))
            outer.attach(msg)
        except:
            print("Unable to open one of the attachments. Error: ", 
sys.exc_info()[0])
            raise

    composed = outer.as_string()

# Send the email
    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as s:
            s.ehlo()
            s.starttls()
            s.ehlo()
            s.login(sender, gmail_password)
            s.sendmail(sender, recipients, composed)
            s.close()
        print("Email sent!")
    except:
        print("Unable to send the email. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code, especially the part that didn't work

Comment: To start a thread on that email function( it takes as arguments the photo name). All good and smooth for the first photo. At the second photo when it finds the intruder it stops and returns an error.("can't start multiple threads" or something similar. I can attach the email code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you'll want to update photos to send while thread is already sending (not running thread with targeted photos to send), so for that you could store photos to send in global variable. Here's my approach to this problem:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def send_email():
    print('started thread')
    global photos_to_send

    while len(photos_to_send) > 0:
        current_photo = photos_to_send.pop(0)
        print('sending {}'.format(current_photo))
        time.sleep(2)
        print('{} sent'.format(current_photo))

    print('no more photos to send ending thread')

photos_to_send = ['photo1.png']

thread1 = Thread(target=send_email, args=())
thread1.start()

photos_to_send.append('photo2.png')

thread1.join()

#started thread
#sending photo1.png
#photo1.png sent
#sending photo2.png
#photo2.png sent
#no more photos to send, ending thread
```